# How can we get and copy xml xpath on Netbeans

Tags: xml, xpath, netbeans

1. Context: I have an XML document opened with Netbeans editor.
2. Requirement: I want to obtain the xpath of "07" text here:

```xml
<Level01>
    <Level02>
         ...
        <Level03>
           <Code>07</Code>
        </Level03>
    </Level02>
    ...
<Level01>
```

I imagine this:

1. To click on "07" text
2. Invoke from a context menu to "Copy xpath"
3. Obtain on clipboard:

   Level01/Level02/Code/

Any idea? Thanks a lot! :)